# Directx 12 ultimate. What has changed?

Tags: directx

We have Windows 10 2004 with new sdk, we have new nvidia drivers with support wddm 2.7 and Dx12U but I still can't understand - how it should help to developers write one code for all platforms?

I don't see any new D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_2, I don't see any new feature to help developers write one code to xbox and pc. Developers still need to check if user has support for all new features as they did before. So what is changed? For me it looks like it was made only for non-tech users who will ask seller give him only GPU with Directx 12 Ultimate sticker and that's all.

Microsoft docs doesn't have any information about directx 12 ultimate, only some blog posts.